# Error message says "subset should have logic value error"

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am having problem with subset in a dataframe and wondering if one expert can explain me what is wrong in subsetting a data frame:

```
d <- data.frame(A=LETTERS[1:4], B=1:4, C=4:1)
subset(d, 3)
# Error in subset.data.frame(d, 3) : 'subset' should have a logic value.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not obvious what you think that command should be doing.

If you want the third row of the data.frame, do:

```
d[3,]
```

If you want the third column, do:

```
d[, 3]
```

Generally, don't use `subset`. It's just syntactic sugar and can get you into trouble as you advance in your knowledge of R.